# How can I add a font to the Font Book Web Collection

Tags: macos, font, font-book

I'd like to add Courier New to my Font Book "Web" Collection:

[image: Web Collection]

I go to the "All Fonts" Collection and search "Courier New":

[image: All Fonts Collection]

After dragging Courier New into the "Web" Collection nothing happens:

[image: Web Collection]

How can I add Courier New to the "Web" Collection? I'm running OS X 10.9.4.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer but these questions may help you narrow down the issue and ultimately resolve the issue.

1. After the Drag & Drop operation is complete, does the font show in Web collection ?
2. If it shows, does the font have any Yellow Exclamation mark on it ?
3. If yes, try repair it
4. If you do not see the font there, **Right Click** on **Web Collection** and **Click Add fonts**, then locate the font in Fonts folder from System Library or Local Library

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the "Web" Collection, creating a new "Web" Collection and dragging in the required fonts from the "All Fonts" Collection solved the issue for me.

Hope this helps anyone else who gets stuck on this like I did.